# Popover crashing on UIBarButtonItem action in iOS

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller

Created a Custom UIBarButtonItem:

```
UIButton *favButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 42.0, 30.0)];
[favButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-navbar-icon-star-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonFavorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnFavorites = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:favButton];
```

And on Button click I am opening a popover.

```
- (void)actionButtonFavorite:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    self.selectedButtonTag = sender.tag;
    favoriteOptionsVC.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(favoriteOptionsVC.view.frame.size.width, (IS_iOS_VERSION_7?190.0:160.0));
    UINavigationController *favoritesNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favoriteOptionsVC];
    self.favoritesPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:favoritesNavVC];
    favoriteOptionsVC.containingPopoverController = self.favoritesPopoverController;
    [self.favoritesPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

But the app is crashing saying:

```
[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a7445e0
```

Sender is instance of `UIBarButtonItem`:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: r u used this line in your project **self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtnFavorites;**

Comment: the sender in your case is a UIButton and not a UIBarButtonItem which is the type actionButtonFavorite: is expecting

Comment: Nope! Sender is instance of UIBarButtonItem, See my edited post

Comment: Two options: either you're asking a `UIButton` to give you a `view`, which it doesn't understand, or you're asking something else for a `view` and that something else has been deallocated, with its memory re-used for a `UIButton`.  If you turn on zombies in your build scheme, it will help identify which problem you need to solve.  If the error stays the same, it's #1; if the error mentions a different class, it's #2. (In either case, a symbolicated stack trace might be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course sender is a UIBarButtonItem, it is implicitly stated in your function. The real sender (the instance that is calling the method) is a UIButton.
Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnFavorites = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(actionButtonFavorite:)];
```

To make your "custom" UIBarButtonItem use this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnFavorites = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-navbar-icon-star-normal.png"]
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(actionButtonFavorite:)];
```

Comment: Hi, I want custom button and not the system button. It is crashing with Custom button.

Answer (score 0):

Made a barbutton item like this -

```
let dotImage    = UIImage(named: "dot")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let searchImage  = UIImage(named: "search")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
       // let shareImageButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: shareImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapshareImageButton(sender:)))
        let dotImageButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: dotImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapdotImageButton(sender:)))
        let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapSearchButton(sender:)))
```

Added popover on this -

```
@objc func didTapdotImageButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShareVC")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
        popover.barButtonItem = sender
        popover.delegate = self
        sender.image = UIImage(named: "close")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi Divyanashu, thanks for the answer. Could you please edit your answer with the correct code formatting to make it more readable.